# Issue with Launching a .PDF from Quosal Create

Tags: .net

My company uses Quosal Create as our primary quoting tool, which the company no longer exists hence no more support. So I turn to all of your brilliant minds to help me figure this out.

Recently one of my coworkers running on a Windows 10 workstation begin seeing this error message when attempting to launch a quote via .PDF from Quosal Create:

> We ran into a problem with your request. Please try it again. Here was the reason: 0: The type 'System.Attribute' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

Based on initial searches of that error, people were getting that error while developing applications using VS. and the go-to fix was to add this reference to an assembly located at:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5.1\Facades\System.Runtime.dll

However, I only see folders for v3.5 and v3.0 under the Framework folder, there doesn't appear to be a .NETFramework folder. (Hidden folders are checked to be shown).

I'm pretty much stumped at this point. I've attempted cleaning his machine of all .NET updates and reinstalling just 4.6.2 and blocking 4.7 thinking it may be causing the issue to no avail. I've done a full reinstall of the Quosal Create client including wiping all registry keys and files related to it. Nothing has helped so far.

I'm curious if anyone has either dealt with this specific case before, or has any ideas that may help me remedy this? Thank you in advance.